# Download data from internet page with WebClient but need to be logged on

Tags: cookies, webclient

I download the HTML from a webpage:

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        string site = "http://www.google.de";
        string result = client.DownloadString(site);
        DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Now;

        richTests.Text = richTests.Text + result;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = result;
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        TimeSpan span = dtEnd - dtStart;

        WriteLog("Seitenaufruf: " + site);
        WriteLog("Time: " + span.Seconds.ToString() + "." + span.Milliseconds.ToString());
```

Now I have the same code on a internet site with a login validation.

I have a PHPSESSION in my Cookie from Firefox that I can use, so I only need a TextBox for inserting this - the problem here: How to give the WebClient client the PHPSESSION with a cookie - can a WebClient sotre a cookie before sending the DownloadString-Request?

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write headers from the WebClient object. For example:

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookies");
```

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx

Comment: It's a simple string formatted as name/value pairs:
string cookie = "Test=test_value; expires=Sat, 01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT; path=/;"

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't worK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075147/phpsessid-cookie-over-webclient-doesnt-work